# VK_OEM_MINUS doesn't work on AZERTY keyboard

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, localization

I use VK_OEM_MINUS (VIRTKEY) as a menu accelerator in my Visual C++ project and it works perfectly when I press "-/_" key on QWERTY keyboards.

But when I use French keyboard layout it doesn't work. The "-" is placed on "6" key in French layout, and it looks like it uses other key code.

I'm wondering how can I use MINUS key for AZERTY keyboards? I'm looking for a way to reuse my code without reassigning accelerator keys. I prefer to use MINUS as accelerator on any keyboard.

UPDATE: I've tried to use ASCII rather than virtual key: `"-", ID_MENUITEM, ASCII, NOINVERT`, but nothing happened, it still doesn't work. (Win7, MSVC2010)

UPDATE: Changed the notebook and used Win7 and MSVC2008 - the ASCII accelerator works now, but it looks like I can't process Ctrl+, Shift+(-) combinations via the accelerator table.

UPDATE: It looks like VK_OEM_MINUS (0xBD) doesn't exist at all for French keyboard layout and it can't be generated by French keyboards.

Comment: Of course `VK_OEM_MINUS` doesn't exist. As you said yourself, the symbol you are looking for is on `VK_KEY_6`.

Comment: David, the issue is I have the hardcoded accelerator which doesn't work on AZERTY layout. I'm looking for a way to reuse my code without reassigning accelerator keys. I prefer to use MINUS as accelerator on any keyboard.

Comment: Insisting on use of a key that doesn't always exist is your problem. Choose a different accelerator. Maybe switch behaviour based on keyboard layout.

Comment: Since VK_OEM_MINUS can't be generated on AZERTY keyboards, I'm going to fake a key by posting (WM_KEYDOWN, VK_OEM_MINUS) when VK_KEY_6 is pressed (only for AZERTY). What do you think? Does it have any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a fast solution I applied because of I didn't want neither to use other accelerators for AZERTY keyboard nor to implement user-defined accelerators.

Since VK_OEM_MINUS can't be generated on AZERTY keyboards, I faked a key press by posting (WM_KEYDOWN, VK_OEM_MINUS) when VK_KEY_6 is pressed (only for AZERTY).